# Class Variable behaving like Instance Variable (Python 3.4)

Tags: python, python-3.x, instance-variables, class-variables

Python 3.4.0a1
Windows 8.1

Class Created:

```
class Bank(object):  
    bankrupt = False
```

Command entered in IDLE `__main__` with the following results:

```
>>> a = Bank()
>>> b = Bank()
>>> a.bankrupt
False
>>> b.bankrupt
False
>>> b.bankrupt = True
>>> b.bankrupt
True
>>> a.bankrupt
False
```

#### Expected output:

I expected a.bankrupt to change to True when I changed b.bankrupt since the variable bankrupt is defined for the entire class and not for a single instance (with `self.bankrupt`) Why is this not happening?

Comment: From a modelling perspective, shouldn't individual `Bank` instances be able to go `bankrupt` separately?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You assigned to a new attribute to the instance instead. To change a class attribute, assign directly to the class.

When looking up an attribute on an instance, look-up 'falls through' to the class, then to the base classes. This is how all class attributes, including methods, are found.

But when *assigning*, this happens directly on the instance. Otherwise you could never assign per-instance values, you'd only ever assign back to the class. Assigning to `a.bankrupt` or `b.bankrupt` will add an attribute to the instance, if it wasn't already there to begin with. To Python, there is no difference between using `self.bankrupt = True` in a method, or to using `a.bankrupt = True` from the 'outside' to assign to an attribute.

Just assign to the class attribute directly (from a method or from 'outside'):

```
Bank.bankrupt = True
```

Note that the same fall-through on read, assignment on write rules apply to base classes; looking up an attribute on a class looks to the base classes if the attribute is not found on the class directly, but setting an attribute on a class do so directly, and not affect attributes on the bases.

For the nitty gritty details, see the *Custom classes* and *Class instances* sections of the [Python datamodel](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html).

Answer (score 0):

With `b.bankrupt = True` you create an instance variable that shadows the class-level variable.

If you want to change the class variable use

```
Bank.bankrupt = True
```

Comment: So there is now both an instance variable for `b` and a class variable called `bankrupt`?

Answer (score 0):

After assignment to instance variable it is created if it was not before. And next time You try to access it You got it from instance `__dict__`.

```
>>> class A:
...     foo = 'b'
...     bar = []
... 
>>> a = A()
>>> b = A()
>>> a.__dict__
{}
>>> a.foo = 'c'
>>> a.foo
'c'
>>> a.__dict__
{'foo': 'c'}
```

This is why You have different values for `a.foo` and `b.foo`
Meanwhile If You modify variable (not reassign it) You will got result which You have described.

```
>>> a.bar.append(1)
>>> b.bar
[1]
>>> a.bar
[1]
>>> a.__dict__
{'foo': 'c'}
```

In this case instance variable was not created.

Comment: Note that when you use `__slots__` on the class *no `__dict__` is used*.